# How to change URL parameter and load dynamic content with that by dropdown value in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, angular-routing

In my angular project I have a component with this url https://example.com/course/cat1/video

And I have dropdown in my component like this

```
<select name="category" id="">
 <option value="cat1"></option>
 <option value="cat2"></option>
 <option value="cat3"></option>
 <option value="cat4"></option>
</select>
```

Now, I want when user click on `cat2` option the URL structure will be like this
https://example.com/course/cat2/video and that will be load data for `cat2` id from ng service.

How can i actually do that.

Comment: use ``router.navigate()`` based on the value of select

Comment: Yes! that's right. I can redirect/navigate by this. but you see i have to change just a parameter not last parameter it's middle parameter. can you please write full code there. I'll be very pleasure for that

Comment: do you have a route like this : ``:id/video`` ? if yes then you can call ``router.navigate()`` method .